# Inserted image by Google Apps Script isn't exported

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

My script inserts a PNG image in the spreadsheet by insertImage() function.

```
  const Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const File = DriveApp.getFileById("**********");     // PNG file in Google Drive
  const Blob = File.getBlob();
  Sheet.insertImage(Blob, 1, 9, 20, 30).setHeight(100).setWidth(100);
}
```

It seems to work fine, but if I export the spreadsheet to PDF, the image doesn't appear in the PDF.
After reloading the spreadsheet on the browser, I can export to PDF with the image with no problem.
How can I export to PDF with the image without reloading the spreadsheet?
(SpreadsheetApp.flush() didn't help it.)

Comment: About `but if I export the spreadsheet to PDF, the image doesn't appear in the PDF.`, can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Just a guess. Resizing can cause the glitches. Try to exclude the `.setHeight(100).setWidth(100)`.

Comment: @Tanaike, it means to exec [File]-[Download]-[PDF document (.pdf)] .

Comment: @yuri, deleting setHeight and setWidth doesn't solve the problem.
But your idea was a big hint!
By changing the parameters from
insertImage(Blob, 1, 9, 20, 30)
to
insertImage(Blob, 1, 9, 0, 0)
, exporting succeeded!
We shouldn't use offsets to export the spreadsheet to other file format.
Anyway, thank!

Comment: Well. Good finding. Thank you too.